# Optimise image picked from camera roll to reduce file size

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app, If user selects an image from camera roll to use as a compnay logo (added to a final pdf) it can take the attached file size from 8mb (with no image) to 29mb in some cases. This is a problem when  user emails the file as its lager than most servers will allow for attachement sizes

```
- (IBAction)schemeLogoPressed:(id)sender {
 LogCmd();
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self.editController presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
   }    

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 {
    DebugLog(@"info dict: %@", info);
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.schemeLogo.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.schemeLogo.image = image;
    NSData *imageData1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSString *path1 = [ICUtils pathForDocument:@"schemeLogo.png"];
    [imageData1 writeToFile:path1 atomically:NO];
```

Is there anything I can do to optimise the picked image size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this line:

```
NSData *imageData1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

to:

```
NSData *imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9f);
```

the second parameter (0.9 float) is the quality. Higher number, higher quality. from 0.0 to 1.0

Comment: Exactly what I was after, simple and clearly explained thank you, plus 1!